# JavaScript calculator cannot calculate double digit numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a JavaScript calculator, currently it can only calculate single numbers at one time. If I try to calculate more than 1 digit, it will not work. This is because my operands are being stored in an array, and the calculate() function takes index[0] and index[1] as arguments. Adding more numbers just fills the array up more.

I am looking for help with getting my calculator to be able to calculate any amount of digits. I was thinking of storing the first number choice in one array, and the second number choice (after the operator) into a 2nd array, and using both of those arrays to calculate the final result. However I'm really not sure how to do this, I have googled it a lot by this point.

**Please do not suggest eval(), I have been advised by the curriculum to not use it**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>
    <h1>Calculator.js</h1>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="input">
            <div class="inputBar"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="buttonList">
            <button id="buttonEquals" class="buttons">=</button>
            <button id="buttonDivide" class="buttons">/</button>
            <button id="buttonMultiply" class="buttons">x</button>
            <button id="buttonSubtract" class="buttons">-</button>
            <button id="buttonAdd" class="buttons">+</button>
            <button id="buttonDot" class="buttons">.</button>
            <button id="buttonDel" class="buttons">C</button>
            <button id="button9" class="buttons">9</button>
            <button id="button5" class="buttons">5</button>
            <button id="button6" class="buttons">6</button>
            <button id="button7" class="buttons">7</button>
            <button id="button8" class="buttons">8</button>
            <button id="button1" class="buttons">1</button>
            <button id="button2" class="buttons">2</button>
            <button id="button3" class="buttons">3</button>
            <button id="button4" class="buttons">4</button>
            <button id="button0" class="buttons">0</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="darkContainer">
        <button id="darkMode">DARK MODE &#127769;</button>
    </div>
    

    <h3>Created by Rhys Hodgson as part of The Odin Project.</h2>

</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
// calculates the user's choices
function calculate(a, operator, b){
    if (operator === " + ") return a + b;
    else if (operator === " - ") return a - b;
    else if (operator === " * ") return a * b;
    else if (operator === " / ") return a / b;
}

// stores DOM button refs
const buttons = {
    "button0": document.getElementById("button0"),
    "button1": document.getElementById("button1"),
    "button2": document.getElementById("button2"),
    "button3": document.getElementById("button3"),
    "button4": document.getElementById("button4"),
    "button5": document.getElementById("button5"),
    "button6": document.getElementById("button6"),
    "button7": document.getElementById("button7"),
    "button8": document.getElementById("button8"),
    "button9": document.getElementById("button9"),
    "buttonDel": document.getElementById("buttonDel"),
    "buttonDot": document.getElementById("buttonDot"),
    "buttonAdd": document.getElementById("buttonAdd"),
    "buttonSubtract": document.getElementById("buttonSubtract"),
    "buttonMultiply": document.getElementById("buttonMultiply"),
    "buttonDivide": document.getElementById("buttonDivide"),
    "buttonEquals": document.getElementById("buttonEquals"),
}
// stores user button choices
let choices = [];
let operators = [];

// user displayed input
let displayInput = document.querySelector(".inputBar");

// buttons display a string on click, adds number to choices[]
buttons.button0.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "0";
    choices.push(0);
});
buttons.button1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "1";
    choices.push(1);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button2.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "2";
    choices.push(2);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button3.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "3";
    choices.push(3);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button4.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "4";
    choices.push(4);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button5.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "5";
    choices.push(5);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button6.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "6";
    choices.push(6);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button7.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "7";
    choices.push(7);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button8.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "8";
    choices.push(8);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button9.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "9";
    choices.push(9);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.buttonDel.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent = "";
    choices.length = 0;
    operators.length = 0;
});
buttons.buttonDot.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent = "I do nothing!";
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.buttonAdd.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += " + ";
    operators.push(" + ")
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.buttonSubtract.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += " - ";
    operators.push(" - ");
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.buttonMultiply.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += " x ";
    operators.push(" * ")
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.buttonDivide.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += " / ";
    operators.push(" / ")
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});

// invokes calculate() with arguments
buttons.buttonEquals.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent = calculate(choices[0], operators[0], choices[1]);
    displayInput.style.color = "green";
});

// dark mode button
let pageBody = document.querySelector("body");
let darkMode = document.getElementById("darkMode");
let footerText = document.querySelector("h3")
darkMode.addEventListener("click", () => {
    pageBody.style.background = "black";
    footerText.style.color = "snow";
});
```

I have tried to convert the value in the displayInput to a number by using parseFloat however this didn't work. I'm pretty lost with what I can do now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly storing each digit to `choices[]`. You can store them in a temporary string and then only push the string to `choices[]` when an operand is clicked.

For example:

Mathematic equation will always be in this format: `199 + 265 = 464`

For each digit is pressed, you push the digit into a string: `str += "1";str += "9";str += "9";`

Then when an operand is pressed, you just take the string and push to `choices[]` which will be `choices.push(str); //where str = 199`

With this structure, you will be able calculate any amount of digits.

```js
// calculates the user's choices
function calculate(a, operator, b){
    if (operator === " + ") return a + b;
    else if (operator === " - ") return a - b;
    else if (operator === " * ") return a * b;
    else if (operator === " / ") return a / b;
}

// stores DOM button refs
const buttons = {
    "button0": document.getElementById("button0"),
    "button1": document.getElementById("button1"),
    "button2": document.getElementById("button2"),
    "button3": document.getElementById("button3"),
    "button4": document.getElementById("button4"),
    "button5": document.getElementById("button5"),
    "button6": document.getElementById("button6"),
    "button7": document.getElementById("button7"),
    "button8": document.getElementById("button8"),
    "button9": document.getElementById("button9"),
    "buttonDel": document.getElementById("buttonDel"),
    "buttonDot": document.getElementById("buttonDot"),
    "buttonAdd": document.getElementById("buttonAdd"),
    "buttonSubtract": document.getElementById("buttonSubtract"),
    "buttonMultiply": document.getElementById("buttonMultiply"),
    "buttonDivide": document.getElementById("buttonDivide"),
    "buttonEquals": document.getElementById("buttonEquals"),
}
// stores user button choices
let choices = [];
let operators = [];
let tempNumber = "0";

// user displayed input
let displayInput = document.querySelector(".inputBar");

// buttons display a string on click, adds number to choices[]
buttons.button0.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "0";
    tempNumber += "0";
    //choices.push(0);
});
buttons.button1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "1";
    tempNumber += "1";
    //choices.push(1);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button2.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "2";
    tempNumber += "2";
    //choices.push(2);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button3.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "3";
    tempNumber += "3";
    //choices.push(3);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button4.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "4";
    tempNumber += "4";
    //choices.push(4);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button5.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "5";
    tempNumber += "5";
    //choices.push(5);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button6.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "6";
    tempNumber += "6";
    //choices.push(6);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button7.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "7";
    tempNumber += "7";
    //choices.push(7);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button8.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "8";
    tempNumber += "8";
    //choices.push(8);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.button9.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += "9";
    tempNumber += "9";
    //choices.push(9);
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.buttonDel.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent = "";
    tempNumber = "0";
    choices.length = 0;
    operators.length = 0;
});
buttons.buttonDot.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent = "I do nothing!";
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.buttonAdd.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += " + ";
    operators.push(" + ")
    if(Number(tempNumber)>0) {
      choices.push(Number(tempNumber));
      tempNumber = "0";
    }
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.buttonSubtract.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += " - ";
    operators.push(" - ");
    if(Number(tempNumber)>0) {
      choices.push(Number(tempNumber));
      tempNumber = "0";
    }
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.buttonMultiply.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += " x ";
    operators.push(" * ")
    if(Number(tempNumber)>0) {
      choices.push(Number(tempNumber));
      tempNumber = "0";
    }
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});
buttons.buttonDivide.addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayInput.textContent += " / ";
    operators.push(" / ")
    if(Number(tempNumber)>0) {
      choices.push(Number(tempNumber));
      tempNumber = "0";
    }
    displayInput.style.color = "black";
});

// invokes calculate() with arguments
buttons.buttonEquals.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(Number(tempNumber)>0) {
      choices.push(Number(tempNumber));
      tempNumber = "0";
    }
    console.log(choices[0],choices[1]);
    displayInput.textContent = calculate(choices[0], operators[0], choices[1]);
    displayInput.style.color = "green";
});

// dark mode button
let pageBody = document.querySelector("body");
let darkMode = document.getElementById("darkMode");
let footerText = document.querySelector("h3")
darkMode.addEventListener("click", () => {
    pageBody.style.background = "black";
    footerText.style.color = "snow";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>
    <h1>Calculator.js</h1>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="input">
            <div class="inputBar"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="buttonList">
            <button id="buttonEquals" class="buttons">=</button>
            <button id="buttonDivide" class="buttons">/</button>
            <button id="buttonMultiply" class="buttons">x</button>
            <button id="buttonSubtract" class="buttons">-</button>
            <button id="buttonAdd" class="buttons">+</button>
            <button id="buttonDot" class="buttons">.</button>
            <button id="buttonDel" class="buttons">C</button>
            <button id="button9" class="buttons">9</button>
            <button id="button5" class="buttons">5</button>
            <button id="button6" class="buttons">6</button>
            <button id="button7" class="buttons">7</button>
            <button id="button8" class="buttons">8</button>
            <button id="button1" class="buttons">1</button>
            <button id="button2" class="buttons">2</button>
            <button id="button3" class="buttons">3</button>
            <button id="button4" class="buttons">4</button>
            <button id="button0" class="buttons">0</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="darkContainer">
        <button id="darkMode">DARK MODE &#127769;</button>
    </div>
    

    <h3>Created by Rhys Hodgson as part of The Odin Project.</h2>

</body>


</html>
```